# Swift: Handle Different Runtimes in a For-Loop

Tags: swift, for-loop, synchronization, runtime

How can I prevent swift from jumping into the next loop, before an optional server request is completed?

I'm fetching a list of visits, which are related to profiles. Some profiles are already in coreData, others needs an additional request to the server. How can I sync these possible differences.

In my current code visit is already changed by the following loops, when Profile.fetch() returns an object.

```
var visit: Visit?
let visitFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Visit")
var persistantVisits: [Visit]?
let profileFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Profile")
var persistantProfiles: [Profile]?


for visitDict in json {

    visit = nil
    persistantVisits = []
    persistantProfiles = []

    do {
        visitFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuid = %@", visitDict["uuid"] as! CVarArg)
        let persistantVisits = try context.fetch(visitFetchRequest) as? [Visit]

        if persistantVisits?.isEmpty == false {
            // update existing VisitObject in tmp context store
            visit = persistantVisits?[0]
        }
        if visit == nil {
            // create new VisitObject
            visit = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Visit", into: context) as? Visit
            visit?.uuid = visitDict["uuid"] as? String
        }
    } catch { os_log("/profiles/visits jsonError", log: OSLog.default, type: .error) }

    // fetch Profile
    profileFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuid = %@", visitDict["visitor"] as! String)
    persistantProfiles = try context.fetch(profileFetchRequest) as? [Profile]

    if persistantProfiles?.isEmpty == false {
        // update existing ProfileObject
        visit?.profile = persistantProfiles?[0]
        // TRIGGER NEXT LOOP
    } else {
        // create new ProfileObject
        // needs an additional request to the server (visit might be changed by next for loop)
        Profile.fetch(uuid: visitDict["visitor"] as! String, context: context) { (profile) -> () in
            visit?.profile = profile
            // TRIGGER NEXT LOOP
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some kind of trigger to start the next loop by code?

Comment: You can use `continue`.

Comment: `continue` is not allowed in the completion handler of `Profile.fetch()`

Comment: Oh sorry! I think *early return* under some condition should do what you want.